# AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject stringValue encoding

Tags: xcode, ios7, ios8, avfoundation, qr-code

Is there any way to get the binary data from AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject or get the right encoding of stringValue?

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *object = [metadataObjects lastObject];
```

In this method, we got the object that "maybe" a kind of AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject, and then

```
    object.stringValue
```

we get the binary data.

However, sometime we may got a object is a class of "AVMetadataFaceObject"
it is defining the features of a detected face......  and don't have the property of stringValue.

We can write this to avoid mistake:

```
    if (![object isKindOfClass:[AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject class]]) return;
```